# Sony Xperia Smartwatch MN2 how to install an Apk file on it?

Tags: android, sdk, apk, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have studied Sony Smartwatch MN2 for couples of week. I still don't get how to use their SDK to install a new apk file. The apk file is programed by me. It can work on Android phone. If someone know how and willing help me. I will be very thankful.

Here's my manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.samplepreferenceactivity2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.EXTENSION_PERMISSION"/>
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/BaseStyle" >
<activity
android:name="SamplePreferenceActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name="SampleExtensionService" />
<receiver             android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.sensorsample.ExtensionReceiver"     android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<!-- Generic extension intents. -->
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.registration.EXTENSION_REGISTER_REQUEST" />
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.registration.ACCESSORY_CONNECTION"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
<!-- Notification intents -->
<action     android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.notification.VIEW_EVENT_DETAIL"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.notification.REFRESH_REQUEST"/>
<!-- Widget intents -->
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.widget.START_REFRESH_IMAGE_REQUEST"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.widget.STOP_REFRESH_IMAGE_REQUEST"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.widget.ONTOUCH"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.widget.scheduled.refresh"/>

<!-- Control intents -->
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.START"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.STOP"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.PAUSE"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.RESUME"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.ERROR"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.KEY_EVENT"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.TOUCH_EVENT"/>
<action android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.SWIPE_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The APK is installed on the phone itself, since the SmartWatch host process runs on the device itself.

Here is a quick checklist to make it work and show it on the SmartWatch:

- Download the SmartConnect (Liveware Mgr) app from Google PLAY. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware
- Connect Smartwatch via bluetooth with the device.
- Download Smartwatch host application (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.smartwatch) - this will be prompted by Smartwatch when it connects
- You can then go into Smartconnect app and check which applications(probably the one you created) on your device are installed for smartwatch, even discover new applications on the Google PLAY store

Please let me know if this is not clear, feel free to ask more explanation.

Comment: I followed your step, but the application I created doesn't come up in Smartconnect app.

Comment: Can you explain via a screenshot, where you are looking for the apps in Smartconnect?

Comment: My reputation is not enough to post an image. I put it on ImageShack. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/img0743t.jpg/

Comment: Did you try installing one of the sample apps(provided with the SDK) and check if that shows up? Post your android manifest code too.

Comment: Yes, I installed the SampleSensorExtension. It didn't shows up. The manifest code was posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work you'd have to spoof the watch into thinking it's talking to the app, because when the phone installs an app for the smartwatch (first generation, I still use Sony MN2) it checks to see if the app is supported by your specific watch, if it isn't than no install, if it is than it'll install automatically but it's taken me 3 years to get this far, and I can still only install the generic music player that barely functions, better off getting something that uses the new wear OS cause it's easier to deal with when making homebrew